# Proving associativity of a certain binary aperation in any complemented distributive lattice

Tags: ring-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders, boolean-ring

If, in a Boolean lattice $(X,\vee,\wedge,0,1,')$ (i.e. a complemented distributive lattice), we define $x+y=(x'\wedge y)\vee(x\wedge y')$, is there an elegant way to prove that $(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$ rather than just opening everything?

For example, in a ring with identity $(X,+,0,-,\cdot,1)$, if we define $x\vee y=x+y-xy$, we easily get the associativity of $\vee$ by opening everything, but we can also do this: notice that $1-(x\vee y)=1-x-y+xy=(1-x)(1-y)$, therefore:

$1-(x\vee(y\vee z))=(1-x)(1-(y\vee z))=(1-x)((1-y)(1-z))=((1-x)(1-y))(1-z)=(1-(x\vee y))(1-z)=1-((x\vee y)\vee z)$

Comment: Some people misunderstood my question, they think I am referring only to the two-element boolean algebra, and I already know a simpler method for it. The problem is that it only worked for this specific example, while my question is about any complemented distributive lattice, such as the powerset os a set, the set of regular open sets of a topological space, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Treating true as $1$ and false as $0$, the xor of $x,\,y$ has the same parity as their sum. (If you want to work in algebra, it's modulo $2$ arithmetic.) Since addition associates, xor associates up to parity. But no distinct truth values are of the same parity, so xor associates.

Comment: Sorry, but by "Boolean algebra" I wanted to mean "Boolean lattice", i.e., any complemented distributive lattice. How can you use the parity method in any Boolean lattice? I only know how to do it in the Boolean algebra $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @DanielKawai In that case isomorphism to ring addition proves the result.

Comment: In the general case, what ring and what isomorphism are you referring to? If you wanted to mean the induced boolean ring in that $x+y=(x' \wedge y)\vee(x\wedge y')$ and $xy=x\wedge y$, this argument looks like circular, because to prove it is indeed a ring, you have to prove, in particular, that $+$ is associative.

Comment: @DanielKawai How do you define xor on the lattice?

Comment: I'll denote xor with $\oplus$ so $+$ can be ordinary addition. If $y=0$, $x\oplus y=x$; if $y=1$, $x\oplus y=1-x$. Thus $x\oplus y=x+y(1-2x)=x+y-2xy$ and $1-2(x\oplus y)=(1-2x)(1-2y)$. This makes associativity immediate.

Comment: Your solution only works for the two-element boolean algebra, the simplest non-trivial boolean algebra.

Comment: You have asked about how to define "xor" on the lattice. It is better to give some example of a boolean algebra that does not have only two elements. You can pick a set $X$ and consider $\mathcal{P}(X)$ with union, intersection, $\emptyset$, $X$, and complement; it will be a boolean lattice, and the "xor" like operation would be the symmetric difference.

Comment: Another example of a boolean algebra is the set of the regular open sets from a topological space.